# Polymer routing in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have create a Polymer based Dashboard which I want to integrate with my Laravel site. My Dashboard is working fine but I have issues with routing in Polymer.

I want my Dashboard to reside at:

```
http://example.com/dashboard
```

I have set up my Laravel route as follows:

```
Route::get('dashboard',function(){
  return View::make('polymer.dashboard');
});
```

and my dashboard urls should be like:

```
http://example.com/dashboard/#!/feedbacks
```

But, I am confused about what setting to make in `app.js`. Current app.js:

```
// Sets app default base URL
  app.baseUrl = '/';
  if (window.location.port === '') {  // if production
    // Uncomment app.baseURL below and
    // set app.baseURL to '/your-pathname/' if running from folder in production
    //app.baseUrl = '/dashboard/';
  }
```

Under these settings, when I navigate to `http://example.com/dashboard`, when Polymer finishes loading, the url changes to `http://example.com/`.

Comment: shouldn't you just use   app.baseUrl = '/dashboard'; ?

Comment: I tried that but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't told the router to not use hashbangs then navigating to /dashboard won't work, it's expecting #!. You'll need to go into app/elements/routing.html and remove the line that says `hashbangs: true`. You'll also need to set the `baseUrl` to `/dashboard/`. Your server will also need to always return the index.html for any URL that starts with dashboard. So if the user tries to go to `example.com/dashboard/feedback` it should send down the index.html page again.

After you've made the change to `routing.html`, go into the devtools settings and enable `Disable cache (with dev tools open)`. Then reload the app to make sure it isn't serving a cached version of the file.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I totally went through your Routing 101 tutorial on YT again to understand what was actually happening :)